# Can't generate PEM to BKS

Tags: android, ssl

Sorry for my English. I try generating from *.pem to bks file. I have a folder and there are 2 files in this folder, **bcprov-jdk16-146.jar** - library and **my-certificate-file.pem** - my pem file

[image]

In console I typed

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias myalias -file <(openssl x509 -in my-certificate-file.pem) -keystore mystore.bks -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "C:/test/bcprov-jdk16-146.jar" -storepass 123456
```

and I got this error

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```